# PHP switch case to update array not affecting array

Tags: php, json, api, post, switch-statement

I'm working on developing an API integration for a small business with FedEx/UPS shipping label creators. I'm more accustomed with Python, so I've hit a few stumbling blocks with PHP, but this is the only one I haven't been able to work out so far. For shipments with multiple packages, each package has to have its individual value, length, width, height, and weight assigned, and there has to be a total value for the shipment as well. I made a switch case for tallying the total value (because the data is sent in a business-specific item code), and that worked fine. But now, trying to use that same switch case to update the payload for the API call isn't working.

Here's what I have right now:

```
for ($j=1; $j<=$_POST['package_count']; $j++) {
        $payload['package'.$j] = [];
        switch ($_POST['insurance'.$j]) {
        case '572':
            $value += 100;
            $payload['package'.$j]['value'] = 100;
            break;
        case '248':
            $value += 500;
            $payload['package'.$j]['value'] = 500;
            break;
        case '544':
            $value += 1000;
            $payload['package'.$j]['value'] = 1000;
            break;
        case '569':
            $value += 1500;
                    $payload['package'.$j]['value'] = 1500;
            break;
        case '570':
            $value += 2000;
            $payload['package'.$j]['value'] = 2000;
            break;
        case '571':
            $value += 2500;
            $payload['package'.$j]['value'] = 2500;
            break;
    }
    $totalWeight += $_POST['weight'.$j];
    $payload['package'.$j] = ['weight' => $_POST['weight'.$j], 'length' => $_POST['length'.$j], 'width' => $_POST['width'.$j], 'height' => $_POST['height'.$j]];
}
echo print_r($payload);
```

The $value updates correctly, but when I get the echo of the payload, the packages look like:

```
[package1] => Array
        (
            [weight] => 1
            [length] => 2
            [width] => 3
            [height] => 2
        )

[package2] => Array
        (
            [weight] => 1
            [length] => 2
            [width] => 3
            [height] => 2
        )
```

Any clues as to why the payload packageJ subarray isn't getting the 'value'?

Comment: After your switch you destroy all your hard work by creating a new array. move your final `$payload['package'.$j] = [...]` to the top instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very end of each iteration you are overriding the value that you are setting in your switch/case.

If I had to guess, you want the weight/length/width/height properties **and** the value. If that is the case, then move the assignment from the end of the iteration to the beginning:

```php
for ($j=1; $j<=$_POST['package_count']; $j++) {
    $payload['package'.$j] = ['weight' => $_POST['weight'.$j], 'length' => $_POST['length'.$j], 'width' => $_POST['width'.$j], 'height' => $_POST['height'.$j]];
    switch ($_POST['insurance'.$j]) {
        case '572':
            $value += 100;
            $payload['package'.$j]['value'] = 100;
            break;
        // etc...
    }
    $totalWeight += $_POST['weight'.$j];
}
```

Comment: Face palming so hard right now... I've been working on this with way too little sleep. Thank you!

Comment: @evie_and_eevees - trust me, I feel that 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new array in this line:

```
$payload['package'.$j] = ['weight' => $_POST['weight'.$j], 'length' => $_POST['length'.$j], 'width' => $_POST['width'.$j], 'height' => $_POST['height'.$j]];
```

Replace it by:

```
$payload['package'.$j]['weight'] = $_POST['weight'.$j];
$payload['package'.$j]['length'] = $_POST['length'.$j];
$payload['package'.$j]['width'] = $_POST['width'.$j];
$payload['package'.$j]['height'] = $_POST['height'.$j];
```

OR

```
$packageValue = 0;     
switch ($_POST['insurance'.$j]) {
    case '572':
        $value += 100;
        //$payload['package'.$j]['value'] = 100;
        $packageValue = 100;
        break;
    case '248':
        $value += 500;
        //$payload['package'.$j]['value'] = 500;
        $packageValue = 500;
        break;
      ...
```

And then:

```
$payload['package'.$j] = [
    'weight' => $_POST['weight'.$j], 
    'length' => $_POST['length'.$j], 
    'width' => $_POST['width'.$j], 
    'height' => $_POST['height'.$j],
    'value' => $packageValue,
];
```

Comment: Much better way to do (2nd part).+1